# GDB error after update

Tags: eclipse, gdb, arm

I use eclipse IDE with stellaris launchpad. It worked fine, but an update came and I'm getting error messages since that. I use manjaro linux.arm-none-eabi-gdb 7.7-2 is installed.

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
target extended-remote :3333
Error message from debugger back end:
:3333: Connection timed out. ,Failed to execute MI command:
monitor reset halt
Error message from debugger back end:
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
Failed to execute MI command:
target extended-remote :3333
Error message from debugger back end:
:3333: Connection timed out.
:3333: Connection timed out.
Failed to execute MI command:
monitor reset halt
Error message from debugger back end:
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
```

The console says:

```
Python Exception <class 'ImportError'> No module named 'gdb': 

warning: 
Could not load the Python gdb module from `/usr/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python exception means that your gdb was installed improperly.  This isn't necessarily fatal, as noted in the message.  However, it is worth fixing, because it means some gdb features won't work properly.

The "connection timed out" stuff means that connecting to the remote target failed.  Something must be wrong there, but there's no way for us to know what.